# I'm having issues with my Power Bi desktop stop refreshing

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

merchants_and_wallets
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
vpay merchant_transaction
Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'isaggregator' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'aggregatorid' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'isaggregator' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'Year' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Cannot find table 'vpay datetimedime'. Cannot find table 'vpay datetimedime'. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'city' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'isaggregator' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column '_id' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'Transaction Amount' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'Revenue Amount' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'aggregatorcode' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Column 'createdon' in table 'vpay merchant_transaction' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression. Failed to resolve name 'verified'. It is not a valid table, variable, or function name. Cannot find table 'Retenshion Rate'. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E.
vpay vpay_users
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
vpaydata dartpay_production_systemwallettransactions
Load was cancelled by an error in loading a previous table.
public combined_view
OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] PostgreSQL: 53100: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp8584.2.fileset/i107of128.p2.0": No space left on device.

I tried to refresh it but it failed

Comment: Looks like you have an issue with the data source. Check your PostgresSQL - seems that it has run out of space "No space left on device.".

Comment: Thank you, but please can I reachout to you in private?